# How to sort a 2d String array with int values?

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, compare, comparator

I can't seem to figure this out on my own. I've got a 2d array,

String Collectors[name][#ofstuff]

I'm trying to use this code to sort it:

```
Arrays.sort(Collectors, new Comparator<String[]>() {
 public int compare(String[] a1, String[] a2 ) 
 {
    return a1[1].compareTo(a2[1]);
 }
});
```

I'm new with Compare, tried to read numerous docs about it but don't really understand it.
Does the sort function just get the information that I want to compare two strings and then does its thing?

For some reason this code throws a NullPointerException each time it's read.

**Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at p1.P1$1$1.compare(P1.java:155) (This is the return statement)
    at p1.P1$1$1.compare(P1.java:152) (This is the Arrays.sort line)**

So I'm attempting to sort the array by its second dimension, the # of stuff. should I be trying to convert those values to int and compare the ints instead?

*Just incase people say don't use arrays, I have to use them for this assignment, I just happened to make everything 1000 times harder for myself by using a 2d array instead of 1d.*

EDIT: Oops I might've made a mistake with explaining the 2d array. Apologies, I've been working all day on this hehe.

```
String Collectors[][] = new String[100][2];
```

Then I have some code that adds into there, and I'd like to start sorting by the second index of the first dimension. I guess I have to fill all the indexes first, and this will remedy the null pointer exception?

**SOLUTION**

The array must be full before attempting to sort! Thank you ILoveCoding ♥

Comment: It means that some elements of your array are null. How do you initialize it?

Comment: Please provide an example of a small 2-D array that you are expecting to sort, what you would like the result of the sort to be, and why.  Your explanation doesn't make much sense to me.  You may be confused about how 2-D arrays work, or you may just be using the wrong terminology when you're talking about them.

Comment: What are you actually trying to use as sorting criterion?  I suspect you've meant to compare `a1.length` and `a2.length` (thus sorting the arrays by length).  `a1[1]` will default to `null` unless you initialize it with some `String` and so will `a2[1]`.  Also, how do you know that the two arrays will have at least two elements?

Comment: Thanks everyone, so to remedy this error I have to fill the array first before it can be sorted? (I have an array extending method I can use to extend it then each time it gets filled instead of just making it large right off the bat)

So for example index [0][0] = Bob and index [0][1] = 5
index [1][0] = Sam index [2][1] = 10
I'd like to sort it based on the indexes that hold the numbers while still keeping the links between the names and the numbers.

Comment: It seems to me from your last comment that you are trying to fake objects with arrays.  But it's really hard to guess what you are trying to do.  Please update your question to include at least a sample input and desired output.  Also see [*“How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example”*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Okay I posted the rest of the code there. What does it mean to fake objects?

Answer (score 0):

All indexes of the array must be initialized in order to do a sort function, otherwise a NullPointerException is returned.

Source: [ILoveCoding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2040251/ilovecoding)